# How do I run a local server for an App Engine / Node.js app with an app.yaml file?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and Node.js. I'm able to follow all the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app) for a basic app without issue.

However, I'd like my `app.yaml` file to contain `handlers` sections to serve static files ([as documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element)), e.g.

```yaml
- url: /app.css
  static_files: static/app.css
  upload: static/app.css
```

The documentation for Node.js on App Engine says to simply run `npm start` to run my server, but that just runs the *Node* server, not the App Engine server that's configured by `app.yaml`. That means my local server serves a page, but the request for CSS fails!

I can't figure out how to run something (without deploying to App Engine) that will serve both my Node app and the static files. How can I quickly start a server that's similar to what will run in production?

Comment: Naturally, immediately after posting, I found [documentation for static files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files) which implies that I should use Node to serve the files locally. Is doing things differently in dev vs. prod really the best solution? Or should I just use express.static in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go either serving locally or using express.static on both environments and both options would be working solutions for your issue.

That being said, I personally don't like the idea of having different solutions implemented for Prod and Dev environments (on a general note) as it may cause different behaviours between your environments and make it difficult to notice errors before they reach the Prod environment.

So I would use the express.static approach on both environments.

Comment: @JosephKaptur Does this solve your issue?